# react-bootstrap form margin causing overflow

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I just got into react-bootstrap today. I want the form to be in a div with margins on left and right side. My jsx looks like this:

```
const Settings = () =>{
   return(
            <div className="content">
                <div className="box">

                    {/* Actual form with course info */}
                    <Form className="course-info">
                        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                            <Form.Label variant="settingsLabel" column sm={3}>
                                Course Title
                            </Form.Label>
                            <Col sm={5}>
                                <Form.Control/>
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>

                </div>
           </div>
   );
}
```

CSS:

```
/* A big wrapper for everything on this page */
.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* The box containing the class settings */
.box {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 30px solid #A6D1DF;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.center-items{
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Gives the form left/right margin and sets text color */
.course-info {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #9E7772;
}

Form.Label-settingsLabel {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: red;
}
```

And the form content overflows the right-hand side of the box, and removing the margin fixes the problem.
However, I still want that margin for styling purposes. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Use margin instead of padding ? padding is calculated within the width because bootstrap sets the  `box-sizing` property to `border-box`

Comment: Yeah actually I tried margin before padding and it did the same thing :(

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet illustrating the issue ? It's Probably some ancestor is interfering, For example `Row` usually adds `margin-left:-15px;` Which is why `Row` should always be within a `Container`